# Cannot Assign Custom Taxonomy to WooCommerce Product via REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently trying to assign a custom taxonomy to a WooCommerce product via the REST API. I created this custom taxonomy named "editoriales" using JetEngine and have activated the "Is Hierachical" and "Show in REST API" options.

When I create a new product via POST, I'm trying to assign the taxonomy as follows:

```
{
    ...
    "editoriales": [1055],
    ...
}
```

Where `1055` is the `term_id` of the taxonomy I want to assign to the product. However, this is not working - the product is created, but without the "editoriales" taxonomy assigned to it.

Furthermore, when I try to update an existing product via PUT and assign the "editoriales" taxonomy, it still doesn't work:

```
{
    "product": {
        "editoriales": [1055]
    }
}
```

Also tried with this code in the `functions.php` file, but got Error 500.

```
// Registro de la API para la taxonomía personalizada "editoriales"
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_editoriales' );

function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_editoriales() {
    register_rest_field('product', "editoriales", array(
        'get_callback'    => 'product_get_callback',
        'update_callback' => 'product_update_callback',
        'schema' => null,
    ));
}

// Obtener los registros de la taxonomía en la REST API de WooCommerce
function product_get_callback($post, $attr, $request, $object_type) {
    $terms = array();

    // Obtener los términos
    foreach (wp_get_post_terms($post['id'], 'editoriales') as $term) {
        $terms[] = array(
            'term_id' => $term->term_id,
            'name'    => $term->name,
            'slug'    => $term->slug
        );
    }

    return $terms;
}

// Actualizar los registros de la taxonomía en la REST API de WooCommerce
function product_update_callback($values, $post, $attr, $request, $object_type) {   
    // ID del producto
    $postId = $post->get_id();

    // Ejemplo: $values = [1055];                

    // Asignar los términos
    wp_set_object_terms($postId, $values, 'editoriales');
}
```

I made a GET request to a product that already has the "editoriales" taxonomy assigned, and I can see the taxonomy data in the response, with term_id as the identifier.

Has anyone else encountered this problem before? Any ideas why I can't assign my custom taxonomy to the product when I create or update it via the WooCommerce REST API? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

It seems yI was on the right track. The problem might be related to the way I was trying to register my custom taxonomy ("editoriales") with the REST API. I also mentioned I want to extend my API to include another custom taxonomy, "autores". I will provide a solution that caters to both of these needs.

This code extends the WooCommerce REST API to handle two custom taxonomies, 'editoriales' and 'autores'. You can add this to your `functions.php` file:

```php
// Add the 'editoriales' and 'autores' taxonomies to the WooCommerce API.
function custom_wc_rest_product_object_type($types) {
    $types[] = 'editoriales';
    $types[] = 'autores';
    return $types;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_product_object_type', 'custom_wc_rest_product_object_type');

// GET Endpoint to get 'editoriales' and 'autores' of a specific product.
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'products/(?P<id>\d+)/editoriales', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function ($data) {
            $editoriales = get_the_terms($data['id'], 'editoriales');
            return (is_wp_error($editoriales) || empty($editoriales)) ? null : $editoriales;
        },
    ));
    register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'products/(?P<id>\d+)/autores', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function ($data) {
            $autores = get_the_terms($data['id'], 'autores');
            return (is_wp_error($autores) || empty($autores)) ? null : $autores;
        },
    ));
});

// POST Endpoint to create a new product with 'editoriales' and 'autores'.
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'products', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => function ($data) {
            $product_id = wp_insert_post(array(
                'post_title' => $data['name'],
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            ));
            wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $data['editoriales'], 'editoriales');
            wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $data['autores'], 'autores');
            return new WP_REST_Response($product_id, 201);
        },
    ));
});

// PUT Endpoint to update an existing product with 'editoriales' and 'autores'.
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('wc/v3', 'products/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'PUT',
        'callback' => function ($data) {
            wp_update_post(array(
                'ID' => $data['id'],
                'post_title' => $data['name'],
            ));
            $editoriales_ids = array_map(function ($editorial) {
                return $editorial['id'];
            }, $data['editoriales']);
            wp_set_object_terms($data['id'], $editoriales_ids, 'editoriales');
            $autores_ids = array_map(function ($autor) {
                return $autor['id'];
            }, $data['autores']);
            wp_set_object_terms($data['id'], $autores_ids, 'autores');
            return new WP_REST_Response(null, 204);
        },
    ));
});

// Modify the WooCommerce product API response to include 'editoriales' and 'autores' in the product data.
function custom_product_api_response($response, $product, $request){
    if (empty($response->data)) {
        return $response;
    }

    $editoriales = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'editoriales', ['fields' => 'names']);
    $response->data['editoriales'] = $editoriales;

    $autores = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'autores', ['fields' => 'names']);
    $response->data['autores'] = $autores;

    return $response;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'custom_product_api_response', 20, 3);
```

Remember, the code assumes you've already registered the taxonomies 'editoriales' and 'autores' for WooCommerce products elsewhere in your code.